# Woocommerce - Is there a way to have the product thumbnails "flow" responsively?

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design, woocommerce, responsiveness

My site is [here](http://www.sub.handmadecrafthouse.co.uk) -

As you can see I'm using wordpress and woocommerce and I'm styling the product archive pretty heavily - I'm also using a custom-theme based on Underscores.

What I'd like to have is a site that shows 6 products per row when at desktop size (>992px), 4 when at tablet landscape and 2 at phone size. The tablet and phone sizes work great, but I can't stop the desktop view from shunting all the images to the left of the page.

I've tried changing the number of columns to 6 and adjust the css to suit the desktop view, it also messes up the tablet size. I've also tried using bootstrap but that seemed to make things even more wrong!

Is there a way to do what I want with css or will I have to remove the columns completely within the woocommerce.php files somehow?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: I've tried adjusting the functions.php as follows -

`add_filter('loop_shop_columns', 'loop_columns');
if (!function_exists('loop_columns')) {
 function loop_columns() {
  return 6; // 6 products per row
 }
}
`

This works on a desktop, but on a tablet it just makes a row of 4 followed by a row of 2 over and over again - which I don't want.

Comment: Always edit your question to show additional code. Code in the comments is usually hard to read. And you need some CSS style rules. Try inspecting your site with Firebug or Chrome's dev tools (F12).

Comment: For reference the products are merely an unordered list element `ul.products` and each product is an item in the list `li.product`

Comment: UL/LI's won't work because you can't put them in a row.